# Problem with findById to display product detail via their Id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to nodeJs and wanted to practice creating a shopping cart. I all succeeded alone but managed to display the detail of products clicked by the user that it does not work:
SUMMARY OF MY CODE

I created in my models folder two js files called user.js and jacket.js which each contain a schema and model separately. In my Controllers folder, I have an index.js file which includes:

```
const User = require ("../models/users")
const Jacket = require ('../models/jacket')
```

My question is that I want to access the Id of these two documents at the same time: Here is my code

```
const getProductId = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const Users = User;
  const Jackets = Jacket;

  !!!. findById(id, (error, product) => {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    console.log(product);
    res.render("product-detail", {
      product: product
    });
  });
};
module.exports = { getProductId: getProductId };
```

My routes folder:

```
const express = require ('express')
const router = express.Router ()
const getIndexController = require ('../controllers/index')
router.get ('/product/:id', getIndexController.getProductId)
```

THANKS TO ALL

Comment: instead od "id" try "_id"

Comment: mongoose is not mentioned here, but can we assume User and Jacket are Mongoose models?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj `findById(id)` is equal  to `findByOne( {_id: id })` so using `_id` here would be wrong.

Comment: yes, Veste and User are mongoose models

Answer (score 0):

By default mongodb autogenerates ids, so having the same id in two different collections seems unlikely unless you customized the ids.

But anyway... Here is a promise-based solution.

```
Promise.all([
  User.findById(id).exec(),
  Jacket.findById(id).exec()
])
  .then(([user, jacket]) => {
    // Or however your template might look like
    res.render('product-detail', { user, jacket } )
  })
  .catch(error =>{
    console.log(error)
  })
```

The key here is that mongo will not wait after it sends a query to the database unless you force it to.

If you insist on using callbacks then you have to chain them:

```
User.findById (id, (error, user) => {
   Jacket.findById (id, (error, jacket) => {
      // This is what we call "callback hell"
      // It might not seem so bad, but it quickly builds up.
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried that

```
const getProductId = (req, res, next) => { 
const id = req.params.id Promise.all ([ User.findById (id) .exec (), Jacket.findById 
(id) .exec ()]) 
.then (([product]) => {  res.render ('product-detail', {product}) })
.catch (error => { console.log (error) }) }
```

it only works for User
Here is my code in my ejs file

```
<h1> <% = product.name%> </h1> 
<img width = "200px" height = "200px" src = "<% = product.image%>" alt = "<% = 
 product.image%>" /> 
<h1> <% = product.description%> </h1> <h1> <% = product.prix%> </h1>
```